# Like's window hidden by other element

Tags: facebook-like, hidden

When I click on "Recommend" the window which button opens is hidden (unvisible) behind the footer.
Actually I've got screenshot to explain it precisely: http://www.diigo.com/item/image/1q1ia/tw30

Of course it's XFBML, because I know problem like this can be found when iframe. Any idea how to fix it?

My weblog address is http://www.votre-site-internet.com/ if you want to check it out by yourself.

Thank you in advance,
Piotr Sochalewski

Answer (score 0):

If you are using FBML, I would look into your CSS z-indexes.  I would suggest bumping up the z-index where the like button is.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't work. I tried high `z-index` but didn't fix the issue.